# Proving that there is a matrix $C$ satisfying $CBA=A $ whenever $\mbox{rank} (BA) = \mbox{rank} (A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices such that $\mbox{rank} (BA) = \mbox{rank} (A)$.
>
> Prove that there exists a matrix $C$ such that $CBA=A$.

All I got was 'row space of BA and A are the same.'

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to think of $A$ and $B$ as linear transformations on Euclidean spaces. The assumption that $rank(BA) = rank(A)$ is equivalent to saying that $B$ maps the image of $A$ to a new subspace whose dimension is equal to the image of $A$. Then the existence of $C$ is equivalent to finding another linear transformation that reverses that process.